# How to store a tree structure of documents (json) and access each parent or children of children via a RESTful url?

Tags: json, rest, graph-databases, document-database, nosql

for example navigating to `localhost/root/parent1/child3/node` will show a json document under this `path` or `localhost/root/parent2/` will show a json document with an array of links to it's children `['localhost/root/parent2/child1', 'localhost/root/parent2/child2/', ...]`

I need a way to quickly traverse all nodes, do filters like `localhost/root?date='05/27/2014'` which will return a tree of documents where a node has a modified date matching the date provided. so `localhost/root?date='05/27/2014'/parent2/` will list only children with modified date matching `05/27/2014`

Would a graph database be best for this or MongoDB? This doesn't seem like an overly custom feature, it's almost like an REST HATEOAS link relationship.

Answer (score 1):

A basic urls for each node:

```
`/api/tree/{id}`
`/api/tree/id:{id}` - if you want to use alternative syntaxes as well
```

An alternative url should be something like this, but it is not necessary to use this one, it is better to use the link relations for traversing the tree.

```
/api/v1/tree/rootNode/level1Child/level2Child/level3Child/...
```

The data part of the response should be something like this:

```
{
    id: "sthfh3rfasvdfn",
    name: "rootNode",
    childNodes: [
        {
            id: "svfwgf3z4ervd",
            name: "level1Child",
            childNodes: [
                {
                    id: "bvniw3k2rn238dgi",
                    name: "level2Child",
                    childNodes: [
                        {
                            ...
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Or instead of the name you can use the index.

The controller part of the hypermedia response should contain [IANA link relations](http://www.iana.org/assignments/link-relations/link-relations.xhtml):

- `self` for the actual node
- `up` or `collection` for the parent node
- `item` for each of the child nodes
- `first`, `last`, `next`, `previous` by pagination of child nodes

Try a hypermedia json format for the responses, for example JSON-LD or HAL+JSON.